# Calling closure and splats

Tags: ruby

Using `yield_self`, an argument of a unary method can be placed beforehand in a method chain. Thus, given:

```
Foo = Struct.new(:one_arg)
```

this line:

```
Foo.new("x")
```

is equivalent to that line:

```
"x".yield_self(&Foo.method(:new))
```

Provided with a method that takes more than one argument and an array, each of whose element corresponds to an argument of the method, the analogy does not work. Thus, given:

```
Foo = Struct.new(:x, :y)
args = [:first_arg, :second_arg]
```

this line:

```
Foo.new(*args)
```

is not equivalent to:

```
args.yield_self(&Foo.method(:new))
```

which is rather equivalent to:

```
Foo.new(args)
```

But I'd rather write something like that. Is there any idiomatic way to achieve array splatting this way?

Answer (score 2):

This is the best you can do, I think:

```
args.yield_self {|ary| Foo.new(*ary)}
```

It's a pipeline, alright. Is it worth all the extra code? You decide.

Comment: Yeah, probably you're right, that this is the only way, but one thing I like about the `yield_self` thing combined with something like `method` is, that it make it easy to write somewhat "dot free" code. A thing this solution isn't.